# Using Multiple Partition Keys in Analytics Query to Store data in multiple azure storage Table

Tags: azure-table-storage, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

I have a scenario where I am sending two event data to event hub with different partition key/partition Id.

Now In my stream analytic I have created two input alias with same connection string (say machine1input and machine2input ) and two different output alias also but here each output alias point to separate table storage.

Now my event data is like this.

```
{
  "MachineName": "M1",
  "Date": "2016-05-26T13:35:30.1557995+05:30"
}
{
  "MachineName": "M2",
  "Date": "2016-05-26T13:35:30.1557995+05:30"
}
```

and here I am sending MachineName-M1 to separate Partition say 1 and MachineName-M2 to separate Partition say 2.

Now I have two azure storage table say `Machine1Record` and `Machine2Record`.
Now I want to write query in stream analytic query window in such a way that Machine M1 record should get store in `Machine1Record` table and Machine M2 record should get store in `Machine2Record` table automatically as data.

I have tried lots of query to achieve this like.

```
SELECT * INTO machine1output From machine1input PARTITION BY PartitionId where PartitionId = "1"
SELECT * INTO machine2output From machine2input PARTITION BY PartitionId where PartitionId = "2"
SELECT * INTO machine1output From machine1input where MachineName = "M1"
SELECT * INTO machine2output From machine2input where MachineName = "M2"
```

But none of them is working.Please do help on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you use a single event hub, as two separate inputs into stream analytics.

You could use a single input from your event hub into your stream analytics job.
Then you could create two outputs from the input stream as follows.

```
SELECT * 
INTO machine1output
FROM BothMachines
PARTITION BY MachineName 
WHERE MachineName = "M1"

SELECT * 
INTO machine2output
FROM BothMachines
PARTITION BY MachineName 
WHERE MachineName = "M2"
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for you reply,But I have already done that but it is not working because when you use my above define json in stream analytic query window and just click on test button,it will not give you any output .

Comment: If you also see this link it suggest that you have to create two different input alias of same event hub to achieve this but it is also not working.https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aad1b6a9-15e4-4716-9c07-6705d0702c74/using-multiple-partition-keys-in-analytics-query?forum=AzureStreamAnalytics

Answer (score 0):

Hi I resolved this issue the only mistake that I was doing here is passing M1 and M2 in double quotes in where clause.I just removed double quotes and used single quotes like this -

```
SELECT * INTO machine1output From machine1input where  MachineName = 'M1'
SELECT * INTO machine2output From machine1input where  MachineName = 'M2'
```

And now it is working perfectly..